# discord.py @ bot.edit_role - NoneType has no attribute colour

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to add the permission 'administrator' by using a command but its outputting the error
"NoneType" has no attribute 'colour'

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def manuadd(ctx, *, arg, role = discord.Role):
    author = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(author.roles, name=arg)
    perms = discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
    await bot.edit_role(author, role, permissions=perms)
```

Comment: Are you sure the exception you mention is related to those lines ?

Comment: You should read the documentation for [`edit_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.edit_role) and the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html). Your arguments look like they should be a converter, and you need to pass the `Server` instead of the author to `edit_role`.  Neither of those should cause your issue though.